# Convert Node.js files to ES5

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, browserify

I have node.js script files which I am trying to re-use inside an ASP.NET application on IE 11.

I follow below steps to use them on IE 11:

1. Create a bundle file using browserify:

> ```
> browserify Module.js --standalone mymodule -o bundle.js
> ```

2. Convert the ES6 version of bundle.js to ES5 by manually converting it using https://babeljs.io/repl.
3. Save the converted ES5 script and include the saved .js file as  in ASP.NET application.

Is there anyway I can automate step 2? Is there any better way to convert Node.js files to ES5?

Comment: Yes, simply use babel as a node module and run it like that. You could use solutions like parcel, webpack or rollup to compile your code for target browsers and never worry about it again.

Comment: thanks for your input @somethinghere. What is the command to convert ES6 to ES5 using babel? Do I still need to use browserify?

Comment: Goh thats a bit more complex and depends on what packager you use. In parcel (parceljs.org) all you need is `parcel index.html` and it will detect all your SCSS, LESS, CSS, JS etc... and convert it to whatever browsers you want. Have a read into things like webpack and parcel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use Browserify, you can use [Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) which is a Browserify transform:

```
npm install --save-dev babelify @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

```
browserify Module.js --standalone mymodule -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ @babel/preset-env ] ]
```

See the [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html) documentation to see how to define your target (`"ie": 11`), by default all ES2015+ syntax will be transformed.