# How to generate single ES5 bundle file from ES6 project using browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, browserify

I am trying to use [`react-vis`](https://github.com/uber/react-vis) library in my project. In their [readme file](https://github.com/uber/react-vis), they have asked to import library by adding following lines in non-node environment:

> If you're working in a non-node environment, you can also directly include the bundle and compiled style using basic html tags.
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-vis/dist/style.css">
> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-vis/dist/dist.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> The global `reactVis` object will now be available for you to play around.

When I did that, I got following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at _classCallCheck (dist.min.js:formatted:23789:27)
    at LabelSeries (dist.min.js:formatted:23823:21)
    at Constructor.render (<anonymous>:1866:23)
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (react.js:6029:34)
    at Constructor._renderValidatedComponent (react.js:11403:21)
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (react.js:5582:14)
    at Constructor.mountComponent (react.js:11403:21)
    at Constructor.mountChildren (react.js:10913:42)
    at Constructor._createContentMarkup (react.js:6812:32)
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (react.js:6734:14)
```

[After a lot of digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914546/getting-js-error-cannot-call-a-class-as-a-function?noredirect=1#comment127077693_71914546), I realised issue was that the react-vis library follows ES6, while my project is in ES5. So, I thought to transpile react-vis library to ES5. After digging a bit in the react-vis repo, I found that [it uses browserify](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/cacb3ca24138e9960caa2a4687505af8995f69ec/packages/react-vis/package.json#L26).

So to compile ES6 porject to single ES5 bundle file using browserify itself, I added `--presets [ @babel/preset-env ]` on [this line itself](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/cacb3ca24138e9960caa2a4687505af8995f69ec/packages/react-vis/package.json#L26) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58374070/1317018):

```
"build:browser": "browserify src/index.js -t [ babelify --presets [ @babel/preset-env ] ] --standalone reactVis | uglifyjs > dist/dist.min.js",
```

I also tried adding `@babel/preset-react`:

```
"build:browser": "browserify src/index.js -t [ babelify --presets [ @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react] --rootMode upward ] --standalone reactVis | uglifyjs > dist/dist.min.js",
```

But in both cases I ended up getting same error: `Cannot call a class as a function`.

What I am missing?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question, albeit for a different bundler? It should just be one question IMO.

Comment: **(1)** because I tried both and failed. **(2)** being new to the world of web development, knowing where did I make mistake will help to build knowledge.